# Unable to edit query in MS Access 2007 which is getting data from SQL View

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a query in my MS Access 2007 and it is getting data from SQL view.I am unable to edit the datasheet in that query subsequently i am unable to edit the sub-form which is getting data from that query. Please help me to edit that query..

Comment: Perhaps the view isn't updatable?

Comment: Can you post the SQL for the query please?

Comment: SELECT * FROM view Where Vessel='09N' and Voyage='0472' ORDER BY Linenumber;

Answer (score -1):

Probably your query is not updateable. What can be done in such kind situation you may find, for instance [here](http://www.fmsinc.com/Microsoftaccess/query/non-updateable/index.html)